# Does detached boost::thread cleans up nicely if function that it executes ends nicely

Tags: boost, boost-thread

lets say that I detach boost::thread either explicitly or implicitly(destructor does it, unlike in std::thread), and that functions that thread calls is guaranteed not to let any exceptions be unhandled...
Does this leaks some resources, or is everything cleaned up by OS when function exits ?
If you wonder why I want it:
I want to have some async fire and forget stuff executing, without calling thread stopping ( for .join()).

Comment: What "stuff" do you mean? Most of resources (dynamically allocated memory, various handles etc) are process-wide, so of course they are not freed when the thread that allocated them ends.

Comment: I mean all the stuff that is used to controll the thread. IDK a lot about system handling of threads so IDK if there are resources that are freed only when you properly .join().

Comment: join() is merely waiting until the thread stops - nothing more.

Comment: OK, tnx, I think it should have been an answer. If you want std::move() your comment and Ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of resources - dynamically allocated memory, various handles etc. - are process-wide, so of course they are not freed when the thread that allocated them ends. (On the other hand, there are thread-related resources, like thread stack and TLS (thread-local storage), which are freed on a thread exit, but I guess that's not what you mean.)

Also, note that join() is not "thread stopping", it's merely waiting until the thread stops. I.e., when you call thread1.join(), you just wait until thread1 ends. It's doesn't deallocate any resources.